# how to view implementation of .net Methods in Visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'd like to see how certain methods in .NET are implemented.

```
 var c = new HttpClient();
 c.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

In Visual Studio 2017, if I hover on GetAsync() and press F12 I supposedly navigate to the definition, but it only contains the documentation, not the actual definition.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ or git-hub or use a decompiler like dotnetPeek

Comment: I've been using dotPeek, but it would be alot easier to browse directly in visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Browse the .NET Framework source code online, with search and navigation powered by Roslyn.

at the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Answer (score 0):

F12 is for "Go To Definition", and Ctrl+F12 will guide you to the implementation. However, I believe you cannot go to the source code of the built in library of .NET using Ctrl+F12, because you just can't.